# Function invocation failed: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

Tags: node.js

This is my code,

```
const express = require("express");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
import axios from 'axios'

const app = express();

.....

module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I'm getting,

> Function invocation failed: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
> property 'exports' of object '#'

But when I use,

`export default app;` instead `module.exports = app;`

Now I'm getting,

> Function invocation failed: TypeError: Cannot set properties of
> undefined (setting 'handler')

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing module.exports = app; also i believe you are using serverless-bundle as a plugin in serverless yaml, weirdly removing it this error goes away for me but i need serverless-bundle too for other things